# Applying "not" across brackets in natural deduction for propositional logic

Tags: logic

I have a quick question. How can I simplify

$\neg(\neg P \lor (\neg Q \land \neg R))$ to $P \lor \neg(\neg Q \land \neg R))$

in natural deduction for propositional logic, and is this even allowed? What kinds of proofs would I have to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is wrong. Just look for De Morgan's law.

Comment: That should help a lot, thank you very much!

Comment: Natural Deduction ? In ND you cannot "simplify" that way; you have to derive the second one from the first by way of rules.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof in a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) to show how one can start with $\neg(\neg P \lor (\neg Q \land \neg R))$ as a premise and derive $P \land (Q \lor R)$. This will show how to approach applying not across sentences within brackets or parentheses. Also this may be what the OP intended to derive.

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/